# If number between range, set value

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, infopath-form

I have an Infopath form that is calculating a percentage.  I need to set a rule that if the percentage is between 80-100, set Field A's value to X.  If the percentage is between 60-79.99, set Field A's value to Y, etc.  I tried structuring rules based on the given range, but Infopath was always returning the first rule.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rule try using the function to set up the default value of the field.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: click on filed properties, there is there little f next to default value, from there you can use different functions to make the calculations.